# Number of embeddings of a (nonsimple) extension of a field to another field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L\supset F$ be a finite field extension of degree $n$ and $K \supset F$ be any extension. I wonder how to prove that the number of embeddings from $L$ to $K$ that restricts to identity on $F$ is bounded by $n$.

If $F=\mathbb Q$ and $K=\mathbb C$, then by primitive element theorem, [we can show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59934/the-number-of-embeddings-of-an-algebraic-extension-of-mathbbq-into-math) the number of embedding is $n$. But I don't know how to deal with this general situation.

Comment: Wlog take $K = \overline{F}$. Then $L/F$ is a tower of simple extensions $L_{i+1}/L_i$ where $ L_{i+1} = L_i(\alpha_{i+1})$ and $\prod_i [L_{i+1}:L_i] = [L:F]$, at each step there are $[L_{i+1}:L_i]_s$ choices for where to send $\alpha_{i+1}$ (the separable degree, the number of $L_i$ conjugates of $\alpha_{i+1}$)

Comment: @reuns But it seems the argument shows that there are exactly $n$ embeddings... I don't quite understand the subtlety here.

Comment: There are exactly $[L:F]$ embeddings  $L \to \overline{F}$ leaving $F$ fixed iff $L/F$ is separable. Otherwise one of the $[L_{i+1}:L_i]_s$ is smaller than $[L_{i+1}:L_i]$ (inseparable arises in characteristic $p$ with things like $\mathbb{F}_p(t)/\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$)

Comment: @reuns Thanks! How do we know that we have counted all the possible embeddings that fix $F$? An embedding restricted to $L_{i+1}$ does not necessarily fix $L_i$, right?

Comment: To see how it works what do you obtain for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i+1}, i)/\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$