# Number of embeddings from algebraic number field to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to understand Jurgen Neukirch, Algebraic number theory, p.28

[image]

I'm trying to prove the underlined statement. In fact, I found associated question in math stackexchange :

[(The number of) embeddings of an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59934/the-number-of-embeddings-of-an-algebraic-extension-of-mathbbq-into-math)

In the question, Arturo Magidin argues that "since an embedding from $K$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is completely determined by what happens to $α$, and the image of $α$ must be a complex root of $f(x)$(the minimal polynomial of $α$ over $\mathbb{Q}$), the n embeddings described above are all the embeddings of K into C."

And.. why his argument is true? Here, 'embedding $\tau : K \to \mathbb{C}$' means monomorphism of fields fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ ? Then we may prove that the image of $α$ by $\tau$ is complex root of $f(x)$(true?).
Or can we prove his statement without assuming that $\tau $ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You need the morphism to fix $\mathbb{Q}$ in order to preserve the coefficients of your minimal polynomial.

Comment: Namely, let $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^N a_j x^j\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we have $$0=\tau(0)=\tau(f(\alpha))=\tau(\sum_{j=1}^N a_j \alpha^j)=\sum_{j=1}^N \tau(a_j) \tau(\alpha)^j.$$ Until now I have just used that $\tau$ is a homomorphism of rings. Now if $\tau$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, you get $\tau(a_j)=a_j$ and you obtain $$0=f(\tau(\alpha)).$$ Thus, $\tau$ permutes roots of $f$.

Comment: Yes, through some trial, I also deduce  $0=f(\tau(α))$ assuming $\tau$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. Anyway thanks !

Comment: By the way, $\mathbb{Q}$ is automatically fixed. Because $\tau(1)=1$ implies (by additivity) $\tau(n)=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then using additivity again it is true for all integers. Finally, using multiplicativity, you get that all rationals are fixed.

Comment: Wow..I coudn't catch it. Thanks for valuable comment. :)